# Controller won't send a response back when using AJAX in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, response

So I've been trying to create a live search bar for the project i'm currently working on. I have been following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9WKRlJ1JGM

But is does not work for me, after a lot of testing I can safely say that the AJAX request is being sent to the correct controller, and that the necessary database queries are being executed. But Nothing is being sent back to the page. I have been on this for over a full day and can't seem to find any articles with a similar Issue. I am also getting no error messages whatsoever, it just doesn't do anything.

Here is some of my code:

Javascript

```
$('#searchbox').on('keyup', function(){
                            $value = $(this).val();
                            //alert($value);
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'get',
                                url: 'livesearch',
                                data: {'search':$value},
                                succes:function(data){
                                    alert(data);
                                }
                            });
                        })
```

Route:

```
Route::get('livesearch','AjaxController@livesearch');
```

Controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

class AjaxController extends Controller {
  public function livesearch(Request $request) {

        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            $output = '';
            $searchresults = User::where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')->get();

            //print_r($searchresults);

            if($searchresults)
            {
                foreach ($searchresults as $key => $searchresult) {
                    $output .=  $searchresult->firstname .
                                            ' ' .
                                            $searchresult->lastname .
                                            ' | ' .
                                            $searchresult->company .
                                            '<br>';
                }
                //return $output;
                return Response($output);
                //return Response::json(['data' => $output]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please ignore the commented code, I used it for testing where my code was failing. And as I said: everything seems to work up to the point the controller has to send the response back.

I really hope some of you guys can help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it getting to that point? Try throwing in some logging for testing.

Comment: Can you show your HTTP request and response? Use network tab in Chrome debugger for example.
Also, you have misprint in your AJAX call `succes` instead of `success`, can it be just the problem?

Comment: It was the misspelling of 'succes'! Thanks for your suggestion, I can't believe I didn't see this myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#searchbox').on('keyup', function(){
                            $value = $(this).val();
                            //alert($value);
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'get',
                                url: 'livesearch',
                                data: {'search':$value},
                                succes:function(data){
                                    alert(data);
                                }
                            });
                        })
```

Your callback is on "succes", but in fact you have to use "success".

Comment: Thank you! I feel like an idiot right now. But I'm so glad it works!